# how can i set alertbody text on runningtime when local notification is fired in ios4 develop?

Tags: iphone, ios4, notifications, local

i'm developing an iphone app.

i'm gonna use local notification. what i want is to set text of alertbody dynamically.

basically, alertbody is set statically when the local notification is scheduled.

but, in my app, the text should be downloaded when the notification is fired.

can i do this? 
anyone help me..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't schedule a notification to have a custom message that is generated when the notification is fired.

If your app is running in the background you could fire an immediate local notification instead. See [Listing 2-2 of this page on Apple's Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13)

Comment: oooh.. it's impossible? :( i thought if there were a function called right before the notification is fired, maybe i could handle it in the function.