# ios local notification with alertbody depending on current location?

Tags: ios, notifications, location, uilocalnotification

What I'd like to do is to set-up a local notification in my iOS app which can remind me one hour ahead of a meeting, and gives me the distance between my current location and the location of the meeting. This means I need to update the alert message when the notification is fired. Is it possible to do it in iOS?

I found this related question [how can i set alertbody text on runningtime when local notification is fired in ios4 develop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019105/how-can-i-set-alertbody-text-on-runningtime-when-local-notification-is-fired-in), but it's more than 2 years old. So I'm hoping there is at least some work-around to have such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation :

> The alert has a property for the message (the alertBody property) and for the title of the action button or slider (alertAction); both of these string values can be internationalized for the user’s current language preference.

[Check here for some example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

Comment: i didn't find any relevant answer in apple's official doc, the excerpt you pointed out is not relevant either.

Comment: You can do like in their example. Just adapt it to your specific case `UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ in %i minutes.", nil),
         item.eventName, minutesBefore];`

Comment: this example doesn't solve my problem. I need alert body to be determined when the notification is fired, for example, showing your current location. In this example, the alert body was decided when the notification was scheduled, but not when it was fired.

Comment: Checkout the onArrival notification in the SetSDK. You can then customize your alert body and shoot of a user notification within the completion handler, https://cocoapods.org/pods/SetSDK